# How to align closing tag with opening tag in HTML with Visual Studio?

Tags: html, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Before pressing enter my html tags are like this

```
<p>|</p>
```

After pressing enter

```
<p>
 |</p>
```

But my expectation like the below

```
<p>|</p>

=>

<p>
  |
</p>
```

How I can do this in visual studio, Please suggest..

Comment: You may find extension for Visual Studio. There may be extension what you want.

Comment: Have you looked under Tools, Options... Search for HTML?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I have tried what I can. Actually I'm new in Visual Studio